Choice of Letter of Rec for PhD
I am applying to chemistry PhD programs to focus on DFT methods. 2 of my applications are due tomorrow, and one of my letter writers (call him Dr. X) has not yet submitted. The letters that I have submitted are from:

A professor I worked with on DFT research as part of a 10-week REU program
A professor I took organic chemistry and upper-level chem courses with and got all As in, who knows me well personally

I am getting worried about this last letter writer, and one of my other professors, Dr. Y, offered to write me a letter in his place, since I need exactly 3. Ignoring the issue of whether he will submit on time, I'm wondering which letter would be better to submit.
I worked with Dr. X for a year on research in organic synthesis, and am taking an upper-level chem course with him right now. I have interacted with him personally a decent amount, although I don't think he is aware of my research focus.
Meanwhile, I did not do research or classes with Dr. Y, and her PhD is in biology. I have been a chemistry tutor at my school for 3 semesters and she was my boss. However, she knows me very well (much more than Dr. X), could speak very positively to my character and abilities, and is aware of my research focus. I know she could write a very strong letter for me, but I am concerned because she's not in my subject and I didn't do research/courses with her.
Which letter would be better for my application?

See this discussion at meta for some guidance: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5492/75368

Voting to close as it is very person-specific and also not even useful for them after 6 days ago!

An easy call if I were in your situation: go with the one who knows you better and hence more likely to provide a meaningful (hopefully positive) evaluation/recommendation. A formulaic letter that's light on specifics is very unlikely to be to your advantage - and may in fact be to your disadvantage. I'd recommend you ask Dr. Y. Good luck.

Thank you! I decided to go with Dr. Y.
